# WP7 + WCF Service: There was no endpoint listening at (URL) that could accept the message

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to develop a Windows Phone application that uses a WCF Service. I'm doing it as decribed here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/5280/

(of course I use my own tables from the DB). The problem is:

- I'm debugging the Class Library project containing the WCF service (to see if some of its methods are invoked properly)
- after the method returns an entity I see the error: `There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:1708/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.` The InnerException is `The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` in the Windows Phone application:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1708/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas ? I tried many answers from that site but none worked

Comment: Can you browse to the service address (http://localhost:1708/Service1.svc)?

Comment: A few more things you can try: use Fiddler (or another network capture tool) to see if the response from the server has any additional information; enable tracing on the server to see if it shows any error message which could also give more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about Silverlight-enabled WCF service on the server side? It it based on CustomBinding instead of basicHttpBinding.

Answer (score 0):

You must change in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig in your Windows Phone Emulator endpoint address from localhost to 
yourComputerName. Thats all:) It works